# Azure App Service sticky slot settings in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-resource-manager

I'm using Terraform to create a slot on an azure app service but I need some of the app settings to be sticky. This is normally done using the "slotConfigNames" in ARM but doesn't seem to be possible in Terraform.

Is this possible?

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service_slot.html

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use azurerm_app_service_slot directly since the Sticky Slot settings are not supported in terraform. But you can make use of the [Azure Template Deployment resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/template_deployment.html) in Terraform.

> The solution will create an App Service with one or more Slots
>   attached to it and will also make use of Slot settings in order to
>   have the configuration tied to the environment as opposed to transform
>   a config file with a CI/CD server such as Octopus Deploy or perhaps
>   use multiple appSettings.json for each environment as you would on a
>   .net application.

You can get more details from this [blog](https://medium.com/@sebandres/terraform-azure-app-service-slots-and-the-twelve-factor-app-config-phew-5bc92cb91fb1).

Comment: Can you please confirm if this is supported in Terraform now?

Comment: It's in progress, see https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1440 and https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/12809

Answer (score 2):

This has ben implemented now in v3.4.0 of the AzureRM provider.

- [terraform-provider-azurerm 3.4.0 (April 28, 2022) release notes](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/v3.4.0/CHANGELOG.md)
- [terraform documentation: sticky_settings](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_web_app#app_setting_names)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: after some investigation into the AZ powershell module for sticky settings (Set-AzWebAppSlotConfigName), I realized that you don't need to set this on the terraform slot resource - you just set it on the primary resource (production slot).

The sticky_settings block has been added to the parent resources (app service, function app), but not the slot.